# Sort Vector with own Struct

Tags: c++, vector, struct

i have my vector with my own Struct of type:

```
struct Absatz_rechts{
    xint yniedrig;
    xint xhoch;
    xint xniedrig;
};

vector<Absatz_rechts> Werte_rechts(Gruppen.size());
Werte_rechts.push_back(Absatz_rechts());
```

now i want to sort the vector

```
for (i = 0; i < Gruppen.size(); i++)
{
    cout << Werte_rechts[i].yniedrig << endl;
    cout << Werte_rechts[i].xhoch << endl;
    cout << Werte_rechts[i].xniedrig << endl;
    cout << endl << endl << endl;
}
```

gives out :

```
10
75
35

12
35
0

8
75
55
```

now the sort with:

```
bool compName(const Absatz_rechts &left, const Absatz_rechts &right)
{
    return (left.yniedrig < right.yniedrig);
}; 

sort(Werte_rechts.begin(), Werte_rechts.end(), compName);
```

The Problem ist the new output:

```
0
0
0

8
75
55

10
75
35
```

Why are the First three now filled with zero ??

Comment: Well, for one, because you created a vector go `Gruppen.size()` (which means it already has that many elements), **then** you pushed even more elements in. Just create the vector without arguments: `vector<Absatz_rechts> Werte_rechts;`, then do your pushes. And stop using `for (i = 0; i < Gruppen.size(); i++)`. just use an iterator on the vector

Answer (score 2):

```
Werte_rechts.push_back(Absatz_rechts());
```

This appends a value-constructed object, its fields all being zero.

After sorting, this will be the first element, so it will appear first when you iterate over the vector to print it. Since you're only printing the first `Gruppen.size()`, and the total size (including the zero-valued one you appended) is `Gruppen.size()+1`, you don't see the last element.